# JFrame not displaying properly

Tags: java, swing, constructor

I haven't done any programming for a while, so I could be missing something obvious here.

I am trying to run the following code, which should create an empty `JFrame` and put it in the center of the screen:

```
public class MainGUI
{
// This initilizes the main JFrame
  public void MainGUI()
  {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Data Deriver");
    //frame.setContentPane(makeGUI(frame));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,180);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new MainGUI();
  }
}
```

However, when I compile this code (using JDK 8.0_45) and run it, nothing happens. No windows open, no errors are thrown, literally nothing happens. It compiles without error, so the code should work, but nothing is being displayed.

I'm really not sure where I am wrong.

Comment: Remove `void` from `public void MainGUI()`.

Comment: fram.pack(); is missing.

Comment: @kiheru Ah, that did it! If you add that as a question I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Can confirm that sain Pradeep and kiheru are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just creating an instance of your `MainGUI` class, but you don't have any explicit constructor, so after that your program exits.

You have to call the `MainGUI()` method which creates and displays the frame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainGUI().MainGUI();
}
```

Or you can make your `MainGUI()` method a *constructor* (which is what gets called when you write `new MainGUI()`) - maybe this was your intention:

```
public MainGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    // ...rest of your code
}
```

**Note:**

Note that you should do all swing-related work in the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread), so you should run `MainGUI()` in EDT like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MainGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

See [**Initial Threads**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be a constructor. I'm not sure why I put void in there, but that was why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

No errors upon compilation, 
This is because the compiler is creating a default constructor for you, because your declaration of MainGUI() appears to the compiler as a function, with a 'void' return type.

What you want (ideally), is to remove the return type declaration from MainGUI(), and you will get what you expect. (a GUI being instantiated upon execution)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
public void MainGUI() {
        ^
}
```

The **void** is causing this to not being the constructor. With the **void** the system is creating a blank (default) constructor which being empty, wont run anything. Remove this and it will work. We all make mistakes from time to time :)